# How to declare multiple prop-types using eslint airbnb in a component arguments?

Tags: reactjs, lint, react-proptypes, eslint-config-airbnb

Function declaration:

```
export default function Labyrinth({ theme = 1 }, { inverted = 0 }) {
```

While declaring proptypes

```
Labyrinth.propTypes = {
  inverted: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.oneOf([1, 2, 3]).isRequired,
}
```

And it shows 'inverted' PropType is defined but prop is never usedeslintreact/no-unused-prop-types

It works but it shows an eslint error.

Comment: Do you read https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unused-prop-types.md?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to declare all inside the same curly brackets just like:

```
export default function Labyrinth({ theme = 1, inverted = 0 }) {}
```